# Prove that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent if $X$ and $Y$ are independent - am I right?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

$X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v's.

I want to prove that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are also independent. Here's my reasoning:

$P(X=x)=P(X=x|Y=y) \implies P(X=x)=P(X=x|Y=y^2) \implies P(X=x^2)=P(X=x^2|Y=y^2)$

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent and supported on $\pm 1$ then $X^2=Y^2$.

Comment: @lulu but they are constant random variables in this case and thus still independent.

Comment: You missed some squares and probably intended $P(X=x)=P(X=x\mid Y=y) \implies P(X=x)=P(X=x\mid Y^2=y^2) $ $ \implies P(X^2=x^2)=P(X^2=x^2\mid Y^2=y^2)$

Comment: I don't think this is the defining property of independence. For example if $X$ is continuous and $Y$ is discrete, then $P(X=x)=P(X=x\mid Y=y)\equiv 0$.

Comment: @lulu in this case $X^2=Y^2\equiv 1$. They *are* independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have ignored $P(X=x\mid Y=-y)$, $P(X=-x\mid Y=-y)$ and $P(X=-x\mid Y=y)$

So try

$$P(X=x \text{ or } X=-x )=P(X=x \text{ or } X=-x \mid Y=y \text{ or } Y=-y)$$
by independence of $X$ and $Y$, and thus $$P(X^2=x^2  )=P(X^2=x^2  \mid Y^2=y^2)$$ demonstrating $X^2$ is independent of $Y^2$

Answer (score 2):

The defining property of independence between $X^2,Y^2$ is that $\sigma(X^2)$ is independent of $\sigma(Y^2)$, where $\sigma$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra generated by the random variables. This can also be reformulanted as 
$$P(X^2\in A,Y^2\in B)=P(X^2\in A)P(Y^2\in B),\, A,B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$$
where $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ denotes the Borel algebra on $\Bbb R$. As such, it can be further reformulanted in an even simpler way
$$P(X^2\le a,Y^2\le b)=P(X^2\le a)P(Y^2\le b),\, a,b\in\Bbb R$$
Can you start from here?

Comment: There is a possibility that the OP is studying probability not based on measure theory and hence the sigma-algebra idea might be beyond the scope. I do agree that thinking about the sigma-algebra's makes the result "almost trivial".